# Object.defaults vs Object.prototype.defaults

Tags: javascript, oop

Im quite confused when to use `.prototype` to extend an object and when not to use it. Like in the partial code below, why not use `.prototype` in `FacebookApi.defaults`, is `.prototype` for functions only?

```
+function ($) { "use strict"; 
  var FacebookApi = function () { 
    return
  }  
  FacebookApi.defaults = {
    request_url: null
  }
  FacebookApi.prototype.request = function (options) {    
    $.ajax({
        url: options
      , cache: true
      , method: 'GET'
      , dataType: 'jsonp'
      , success: function (data) {
        FacebookApi.prototype.userinfo(data)
      }
    })
    return
  }
  window.facebookapi = new FacebookApi();

  $(document)
    .on('load', facebookapi);

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: `$(document).on('load', new FacebookApi());` does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where your sample code comes from, but generally you want to use `prototype` if you want child classes to be able to access it, or if you want to be able to access it through `this`.

The `defaults` in your example code would correspond to a `static` variable in Java - it can be easily referred to within the class or outside of it, but you can't use `this.defaults` to fetch it. Also, child classes wouldn't be able to override, and could only access the fully-qualified name (`FacebookApi.defaults`) - although in your example, you're declaring `FacebookApi` inside a function, so it's only visible in there.

Hope this helps clarify a bit!

Comment: it comes from my superior... Thanks it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
var Person = function (name) {
    var person = this;
    person.name = name;
    person.breaths_taken = 0;
    person.next_breath;

    person.breathe();
};

Person.time_between_breaths   = 2300;
Person.last_person_to_breathe = null;
Person.last_person_to_die     = null;
Person.list_of_the_dead       = [];



Person.prototype.breathe = function () {
    var person = this,
        time_to_wait = Person.time_between_breaths;

    person.breaths_taken += 1;
    Person.last_person_to_breathe = person;
    person.next_breath = setTimeout(function () { person.breathe(); }, time_to_wait);
};

Person.prototype.die = function () {
    var person = this;
    person.isAlive = false;
    clearTimeout(person.next_breath);
    Person.last_person_to_die = person;
    Person.list_of_the_dead.push(person);
};


var bob    = new Person("Bob" ),
    doug   = new Person("Doug"),
    bernie = new Person("Bernie");

bernie.die();

console.log(Person.last_person_to_die.name); // Bernie
```

`.prototype` values are public-static values which are given to ***each instance***, whereas properties/methods put on the constructor are simply public properties which are accessible from the constructor, the same way you could add a property to any other object.

What it does help with is organizing code, between what should be public, and apply to the class in general (but shouldn't be given to every instance...  ...like a reference to an array of all other instances, or config-data that should be fed to the constructor of every new instance from here on, et cetera)...

...while `.prototype` properties are just added as references to each instance.

Basically the constructor will say `for (var key in this.constructor.prototype) { this[key] = this.constructor.prototype[key]; }`.

The example up top should illustrate this rather well, hopefully.